# Deriving ${\rm var}(\overline{X})$ from expected value definition

Tags: variance, mean, sample

I want to show ${\rm var}(\overline{X})$ is $\sigma^2/ n$ for $n$ independent random variables each with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$.  I would like to show this using:

$$ E(\overline{X} - \mu) ^ 2 $$

I'm doing something wrong in my own calculations because it's not reducing to $\sigma ^ 2/ n$.

Any thoughts/comments?  Thanks!  Diane

Comment: Maybe if you could post some of your own work, someone could point out where you are going astray?  Else the calculation is a fairly standard one found in most textbooks, and people might not want to bother typing it all in here (unless they have a canned answer in their files that they can paste in here easily).  Looks a lot like homework too, and if so, please add the homework tag.

Comment: E((Xbar - mu) ^ 2) = E(Xbar ^ 2 - 2 * Xbar * mu - mu ^ 2) =   E(Xbar ^ 2) - 2 * mu * E(Xbar) + E(mu ^ 2) = E(Xbar ^ 2) - 2 * mu ^ 2 + mu ^ 2 = E(Xbar ^ 2) - mu ^ 2.  So, I'm stuck with what to do with E(Xbar ^ 2).  That's why I was thinking there is some "trick" or something I'm missing.

Comment: $$E[(Y-\mu_Y)^2] = E[Y^2] - 2\mu_YE[Y] + \mu_Y^2 = E[Y^2]-mu_Y^2$$ since $E[Y] = \mu_Y$.  So you have an incorrect sign in the expansion.  Also, try writing $$\bar{X}-\mu = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mu)$$ and $$E[(\bar{X}-\mu)^2] = \frac{1}{n^2}E\left[\sum_i (X_i-\mu)^2 + \sum_i\sum_{j\ne i}(X_i-\mu)(X_j-\mu)\right].$$ Can you figure out which expectations are $\sigma^2$ and which are $0$, and why?

Comment: OK, ignore the first two sentences of my previous comment: your expression is correct now.  The first two sentences of my previous comment were based on a draft version of your write-up, and you have corrected it in the final version.  Unfortunately, it is too late to edit my own previous comment.

Comment: Yes!  I think the biggest help was writing out Xbar - mu as the summation you have above.  Then everything is quite clear.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If each observation $X_i$ has standard deviation $\sigma$ then they each have $Var(X_i)=\sigma^2$. As they are independent, we get $Var(\sum_i X_i)= n\sigma^2$. This implies that $Var(n^{-1}\sum_i X_i)= n^{-2}n\sigma^2$, and after cancellation is states that $Var(\bar X)=\sigma^2/n$. If you want to use $E((\bar X - \mu)^2)$, then replace $X_i$ by $X_i-\mu$ everywhere in this argument... but it doesn't make any difference.